# For Honor not using High Performance card

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card, for-honor

I have the open beta of *For Honor*, but when I play it it doesnt run the smoothest, and in the games options it says that its using the intel graphics card, while I have a Nvidia GT 750M installed too.

I've set the application to use the Nvidia through the control panel, and the 3D settings but it doesn't make a difference, the game still is kinda slow and says its using the Intel graphics.

Any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your connections in the back of your PC.  I've had this kind of thing happen in other games when I accidentally plugged my HDMI cable into the wrong socket.

My PC has a graphics card with an HDMI socket or two, but it also has a separate HDMI socket specifically for the Intel card.  If I accidentally plug my HDMI cable into that separate Intel socket, the graphics for that monitor will always go only through the Intel card.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that worked for some people which is to ***Find the exe in the install folder, right click, and choose to run with the nvidia gpu*** I think it might work for you and If not try using the NVidia control panel

Comment: Which people did this work for? Like your other answers: they'd be a lot better if you could provide the sources from which you found the information.

Comment: sorry I didn't pay much attention